# How not to trim in C#

Tags: c#, html

If we are programming via C# in web , when we give it a string it will trim it by default when it shows that string in browser , I'm looking for a way to pretend this action , would you please help me?

Comment: Don't understand this well `when we give it a string it will trim it by default when it shows that string in browser`?

Comment: Could you add your actual code? What framework are you using? What are you trying to do and what is the result?

Comment: One way is to wrap the text in a `<pre>` tag when you render it.

Comment: HTML doesn't normally preserve redundant white-space (except in a few tags like `<pre>`); is that what you are talking about here?

Comment: it doesn't 'trim by default when it shows that string in browser,' html only shows one space character by default.

Comment: When you have plain text inserted in an HTML page, unless it's contained within certain tags (e.g. `<pre>`), the whitespace will be collapsed. That's an HTML feature implemented by browsers. It's not something specific to C#.

Comment: "It's a feature, not a bug" :-)

Answer (score 2):

Well, this is not a feature of C# but of HTML, which collapses white-space. In this case you could explicitly convert spaces to `&nbsp;` and line breaks to `<br>` in your result HTML. Also, you could use the CSS [`white-space` property](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_text_white-space.asp) .